# Using ruby, Sinatra and Mandrill how can I access individal elements from an api call and print as HTML?

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra, mandrill

I want to print, as HTML, elements from a returned JSON object. The ruby code is:

```
get '/get_template_info' do
    mandrill = Mandrill::API.new  
    name = "blah"
    result = mandrill.templates.info name
end
```

The jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".result" ).on( "click", "#edit_template", function() {
$.getJSON("/get_template_info?name=blah", function(data) {
  $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
         var template_txt = '<p>' + this["code"] + '</p>';
        $(".edit_div").append(template_txt);
                            });//end each
            });//end json
    });//end click
});//end doc
```

In the firebug console, this is what I get:

```
{"slug":"blah","name":"blah","code":"blah is the message\r\n\r\n<p>and blah is how it is</p>\r\n<p> I hope it gets better soon </p>","publish_code":"blah is the message\r\n\r\n<p>and blah is how it is</p>\r\n<p> I hope it gets better soon </p>","published_at":"2014-02-06 03:36:04","created_at":"2014-02-05 09:08:06.73429","updated_at":"2014-02-06 03:36:04.28132","publish_name":"blah","labels":["mylabel"],"text":"example text","publish_text":"example text","subject":"this is a subect","publish_subject":"this is a subect","from_email":"rich@pchme.com","publish_from_email":"rich@pchme.com","from_name":"Rich","publish_from_name":"Rich"}
```

but the jQuery snippet this["code'] is printed, in the edit_div, as "undefined"!

What's wrong here guys? All help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the callback you provide to `$.each`, your code seems to want `this` to be the same as `data`, but actually it's the same as `value`.  So, if you do *this*:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".result" ).on( "click", "#edit_template", function() {
    $.getJSON("/get_template_info?name=blah", function(data) {
      $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        console.log(key + ":" + value);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

You will get:

```
slug:blah VM770:2
name:blah VM770:2
code:blah is the message

<p>and blah is how it is</p>
<p> I hope it gets better soon </p> VM770:2
publish_code:blah is the message

<p>and blah is how it is</p>
<p> I hope it gets better soon </p> VM770:2
published_at:2014-02-06 03:36:04 VM770:2
created_at:2014-02-05 09:08:06.73429 VM770:2
updated_at:2014-02-06 03:36:04.28132 VM770:2
publish_name:blah VM770:2
...
```

In your case, you are going straight for the "code" key, so you could just do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".result" ).on( "click", "#edit_template", function() {
    $.getJSON("/get_template_info?name=blah", function(data) {
      var template_txt = '<p>' + data["code"] + '</p>';
      $(".edit_div").append(template_txt);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, I will give this a shot. In fact I have already solved it (in a different way) but I will test out your suggestion and revert. I appreciate your time and help.